# Extract Json field value along with HTTP response from Curl output

Tags: json, bash, parsing

I'm trying to write a Bash script in which the below given curl is being fired on an application hosted on local server and i need to extract the following values from the curl response and store them in seperate variables:

1) The HTTP response code ie. 201
2) The ETag value: ie. 292a74f6-6999-403c-bc3c-d78af9d98a2a
3) The value of "sub" from json response ie. 11deadd1-ca08-4995-aa4b-a980307f2b1d

```
`curl -X POST  -v -sS http://localhost:8087/idp-backend/profile/   -H 'accept: application/json'   -H 'content-type: application/json'   -H 'x-int-opco-id: NV'   -d '{"user_details": {
                "name": "myname",
                "given_name": "Diego",
                "family_name": "Maradona",
                "middle_name": "Armando",
                "email": "test@gmail.com",
                "email_verified": "true",
                "gender": "male",
                "phone_number": "491234569999",
                "phone_number_verified": true,
                "address": {
                    "street_address": "6767 Collins Ave",
                    "locality": "Miami Beach",
                    "region": "FL",
                    "postal_code": "33141",
                    "country": "DEU"
                }
            },
            "device_details": {
                "user_agent": "iOS",
                "device_id": "123123123123123123",
                "ip_address": "1.2.3.4"
            },
            "security_details": {
                "password": "India@1234",
                                    "security_questions": [{
                        "question": "Who is God?",
                        "answer": "me"
                    }]
                }
            }'


Response:

* About to connect() to localhost port 8087 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1... connected
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8087 (#0)
> POST /idp-backend/profile/ HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.27.1 zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2
> Host: localhost:8087
> accept: application/json
> content-type: application/json
> x-int-opco-id: NV
> Content-Length: 1471
> Expect: 100-continue
>
< HTTP/1.1 100
< HTTP/1.1 201
< Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=AFB7012E00510A9627F5A6B49C0CB3E1; Path=/idp-backend; HttpOnly
< X-Application-Context: preprod-idp-crm
< ETag: 292a74f6-6999-403c-bc3c-d78af9d98a2a
< Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Date: Mon, 09 Apr 2018 13:24:35 GMT
<
{"user_details":{"sub":"11deadd1-ca08-4995-aa4b-a980307f2b1d","name":"myname","given_name":"Diego","family_name":"Maradona","middle_name":"Armando","email":"shiv.mishra@vodafone.com","email_verified":true,"gender":"male","zoneinfo":"CET","locale":"AR","phone_number":"491234567893","phone_number_verified":true,"is_blocked":false,"updated_at":"2018-04-09T13:24:35Z","status":"active","market":"NV","address":{"street_address":"6767 Collins Ave","locality":"Miami Beach","region":"FL","postal_code":"33141","country":"de"}},"kyc_details":{"status":"not-started","last_updated":"2018-04-09T13:24:35Z","history":[{"status":"not-started","timestamp":"2018-04-09T13:24:35Z","comment":"User updated status with: not-started"}],"completeness":"partial","completeness_last_update":"2018-04-09T13:24:35Z"},"links":{"self":{"href":"http://localhost:8087/idp-backend/profile/11deadd1-ca08-4995-aa4b-a980307f2b1d"},"urn:vodafoneid:profile:update":{"href":"http://localhost:8087/idp-backend/profile/11deadd1-ca08-4995-aa4b-a980307f2b1d","method":"PATCH","data":{"name":"{name}","given_name":"{given_name}","family_name":"{family_name}","middle_name":"{middle_name}","preferred_username":"{preferred_username}","nickname":"{nickname}","profile":"{profile_url}","picture":"{picture_url}","website":"{website_url}","email":"{email_address}","email_verified":false,"gender":"{gender}","birthdate":"{birthdate}","birthplace":"{birthplace}","zoneinfo":"{zoneinfo}","locale":"{locale}","phone_number":"{phone_number}","phone_number_verified":true,"is_blocked":false,"status":"<active|inactive>","address":{"street_address":"{street_address}","locality":"{locality}","region":"{region}","postal_code":"{postal_code}","country":"{country}"},"vodafone_phone_number":false},"headers":[{"x-int-opco-id":"NV","Content-Type":"application/json"}]},"urn:vodafoneid:profile:delete":{"href":"http://localho* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
* Closing connection #0
st:8087/idp-backend/profile/11deadd1-ca08-4995-aa4b-a980307f2b1d","method":"DELETE","headers":[{"x-int-opco-id":"NV"}]}}}
```

`
I'm trying to store the curl response in a variable named content and trying to do echo $content | jq -r '.[] .sub.

However, this is not working , moreover even the HTTP response and Etag value is not a part of the Json Body so ,How do i write the bash script so that i will be able to store all the above 3 values(http, Etag & sub) in different variables in one shot.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `jq` filter should be `.user_details.sub`.

Comment: Thanks that worked for me. I used -r option as well to remove the double quotes. Can you please tell be how do we retrieve the sub from following json response:

Comment: Thanks that worked for me. I used -r option as well to remove the double quotes. Can you please tell be how do we retrieve the sub with jq from following json response:
{"links":{"self":{"href":"http://localhost:8087/idp-backend/profile/lookup?qstatus=active&qemail=shiv.mishra@vodafone.com&offset=0&count=10"}},"offset":0,"count":10,"totalItems":1,"items":[{"sub":"11deadd1-ca08-4995-aa4b-a980307f2b1d","name":"testuser","given_name":"Diego","family_name":"Maradona","middle_name":"Armando","nickname":"masterofuniverse","phone_number":"491234567893","status":"active","country":"de"}}]}

Answer (score 0):

You can grep the output as it is shown to standard out and use something like the -P and -o flags to get the parts that you want.
The -P (or --perl-regexp) allows you to grep for anything that matches your regex and when used together with the -o (or --only-matching) you can be very specific about what you want to echo out.

So for example adding `| grep -Po '(?i)(?<http>^< http.*$)'` to the end of your curl will return the lines which start with case insensitive `< http`
blake.payne tmp $ cat test | grep -Po '(?i)(?^< http.*$)'
Which gives me the following from your example:

`< HTTP/1.1 100
 < HTTP/1.1 201`

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply, however it still doesn't give me the expected output:

Here is my script:

Comment: As mentioned , i need to extract,Both, the HTTP_response(ie. 201) & Etag header value and store them in a variable. I'm able to extract the value of sub field from Json body which is the last line of the response.It is giving me all the headers in response.

Comment: Apologies @MayurKadam I do not see your script where you have commented saying it is there.
I only get you one part so that you could see how it was done, however, add this to the end and that will return all the parts you want
`| grep -Po '(?i)(?<http>^< http.*$)|(?<etag>^< etag.*$)|(?<sub>sub".*)'`